# Major compaction in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a 4 node brisk cluster with 2 Cassandra nodes in Cassandra DC and 2 brisk nodes in Brisk DC. I stress tested this set up using stress tool which is being shipped along with cassandra for 10 Million writes

On executing

```
$ ./nodetool -h x.x.x.x compactionstats

pending tasks: 17
          compaction type        keyspace   column family bytes compacted     bytes total  progress
                    Major       Keyspace1       Standard1        45172473        60278166    74.94%
```

AFAIK major compaction is manually triggered from node tool. But I'm able to see that it has been triggered automatically.
Is this a desired behavior? If so what are all the situations this may occur?

Regards,
Tamil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the doc:

> Compactions are triggered when at least N SStables have been flushed
> to disk, where N is tunable and defaults to 4.

"Minor" compactions merge sstables of similar size; "major" compactions merge all sstables in a given ColumnFamily.

Again from the doc:

> A major compaction is triggered either via nodeprobe, **or automatically**:
>
> Nodeprobe sends TreeRequest messages to all neighbors of the target
> node: when a node receives a TreeRequest, it will perform a readonly
> compaction to immediately validate the column family.
>
> Automatic compactions will also validate a column family and broadcast
> TreeResponses, but since TreeRequest messages are not sent to
> neighboring nodes, repairs will only occur if two nodes happen to
> perform automatic compactions within TREE_STORE_TIMEOUT of one
> another.

You may find more info [here](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable) and [here](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArchitectureAntiEntropy)